# VB.Net - Char.IsNumber input Roman numerals

Tags: vb.net, char, roman-numerals

I just noticed that the Char.IsNumber function accepts Roman numerals (amongst other things) as a number.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8t708dh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But Roman numerals would be strings ("III", "IV") or letters ("V", "X"), how can you input Roman numerals into this method for it to return true?

It makes me wonder what else could be entered that we may not consider to be a number.
The number symbol (#) returns false from the Char.IsSymbol method I has discovered for eg.

Comment: Microsoft's backcompat is legendary.  But no, Char.IsNumber("V"c) returns False.  You have to use the dedicated glyphs in Unicode to get that to work, like U+2164.  Aka "Ⅴ"c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *But Roman numerals would be strings ("III", "IV")…*

In general, you are correct that Roman numbers tend to be `string`s, not `char`s.

However, for certain specific Roman numerals — Ⅰ, Ⅱ, Ⅲ, Ⅳ, …, Ⅻ, Ⅼ, Ⅽ, Ⅾ, Ⅿ, as well as their lower-case versions — Unicode has dedicated (non-surrogate) codepoints. I have just used them! See the following resources for details:

- ['Roman numerals in Unicode' on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode#Roman_numerals_in_Unicode).
- [This Unicode PDF chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2150.pdf) shows the Roman numerals.

Note that each of these numerals is a *single* (non-surrogate) Unicode code point, and as such will fit into just one .NET `System.Char`.

> *…how can you input Roman numerals into this method for it to return true?*

Here is an example in VB.NET:

```vb
Dim romanNumeralFour As Char = ChrW(&H2163)      ' or: "Ⅳ"c
Assert.IsTrue(Char.IsNumber(romanNumeralFour))
```

And here is the C# version:

```cs
const char romanNumeralFour = '\u2163';         // or: 'Ⅳ'
Assert.IsTrue(char.IsNumber(romanNumeralFour));
```

Like [Hans Passant commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235054/vb-net-char-isnumber-input-roman-numerals/28235112#comment44832180_28235054), note that this won't work if you use Latin letters, such as `M`; the Roman numeral `Ⅿ` is a different character, even if it might look the same (depending on your display font)!

> *It makes me wonder what else could be entered that we may not consider to be a number.*

That method ought to return `True` for any characters from these Unicode character categories:

- `Nd` / [`UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx) ([list of characters in this category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm))
- `Nl` / [`UnicodeCategory.LetterNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx) ([list of characters in this category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm))
- `No` / [`UnicodeCategory.OtherNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx) ([list of characters in this category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm))

Comment: Thanks! I did a fair bit of research after asking this questing. I created test and used this site: http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ to help me convert unicode into dec point code I could put into ChrW(). 
It's funny to think, I wonder if .Net considers Counting-rod numerals to be numbers? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode#Counting-rod_numerals